# Expectation of $(1-\frac{2}{n})^T$ where $T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$ be independent.
Compute $\mathbb{E}((1-\frac{2}{n})^T)$ where $T := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.
How would I start this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$(1-2/n)^{\sum_i X_i} = \prod_i (1-2/n)^{X_i}$$  Next use independence.

Comment: @Mr. That, or use the fact that the distribution of $T$ is well-known (and certainly in your notes).